# XML - Force update

Tags: java, xml

I'm currently working on my homepage for my soccer team and I would very much like that the browsers are forced to update the XML-parts on every visit for the below mentioned subpage. Is that possible?

http://www.halfmen.dk/profiler/jens-andersen.htm

Ps: I have used the coding for the XML-parts from w3schools.

Thanks in advance...

:o) McClaud

Comment: Use cache control headers

Comment: Hi DavidB. Can you suggest the right header for me to use and precise the place for it to be? I'm a bit new to this. Thanks in advance. :o)

Comment: There you go, see my answer below. PS - Id advise you do a lot of reading as well :)

Comment: Please post your code here, not a link to your site.

Answer (score 1):

McClaud,

If you are having problems with browser cache, you could easily add a random parameter to each xml file to force the browser to refresh the data.

Modifying the code you're using (Look at the end of the loadXMLDoc call):

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("../alltime/xml-alltimestatistik.xml?v="+Math.floor((Math.random()*5000)+1).toString());
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("KAMPSNIT")[7];
y=x.childNodes[0];
document.write(y.nodeValue);
```

Note that you can create the xmlDoc only once in the document and then reuse it every time you need it.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Yes, is a htm page, but it has javascript inside. In the question he clearly says that he wants to force the update of the XML parts.

Comment: Hi, I have tried both suggestions in three different browsers (IE/FF/GC) - but unfortunately without success. When I used your suggestion, Alexis, the node didn't display? Maybe it didn't work because of loadxmldoc.js (http://www.halfmen.dk/scripts/loadxmldoc/loadxmldoc.js).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, McClaud, i've edited my answer, look at the "?v=" at the end of ".xml". Note also the formulae, now takes random numbers from 1 to 5000

Comment: Sorry dude, I didnt read correctly. mt bad

Comment: Thank you Alexis... Now it works. All the best

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Whack that between the `<head></head>` tags

Comment: Hi, I have tried both suggestions in three different browsers (IE/FF/GC) - but unfortunately without success. When I used your suggestion, Alexis, the node didn't display? Maybe it didn't work because of loadxmldoc.js (http://www.halfmen.dk/scripts/loadxmldoc/loadxmldoc.js).